# What does the number displayed at the end of the file in an Eclipse project explorer mean?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Galileo and when I open project explorer, in the list of files shown, I can see a number at the end of every file or at the end of the package, some are same and some are different. What does these number indicate?

[image]

Comment: It could be the version of that file as shown by the Version management system, ( assuming yours is SVN ? )

Comment: yes we are using SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has 'Label Decorations' (search label in Preferences.
Depending on your settings, that can be various information (file size, svn revision etc...)